# Fetch and refresh Twitter user's friends with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

So basically I want to allow my users to connect to my website with Twitter in order to fetch their friends (followings), save these relationships to a table and keep this table updated when there is a change on Twitter (new follow, unfollow).

For the fetch part, I handle it with https://github.com/sferik/twitter. But I don't really know how to get started with the "update" part considering I could have a large users base and Twitter's rate limits. I thought about using a background job and play with rate limits, but it doesn't look like a viable or scalable option.

Any ideas to put me on tracks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the twitter api, but it would be magnificent if you could have a webhook that gets to notifications form twitter every time a user of your app gets or looses a follower so that every 100 notifications or so you trigger a background job using active job; although I don't think that's very convenient for twitter either.

If that's not an option maybe you could have a background job for now and have it running on a special dyno or dynos when your users base grows large enough (I can explain myself in heroku terms).